# Add Polygons to SpatialPolygons via loop / iteration using R?

Tags: r, iterator, loop, sp

Just out of interest: I'm creating a SpatialPolygon (R with package "sp") with a number of Polygons within. Is there a way to loop this task? I'm doing it manually as follows. The Polygons consist of 5 points each (i.e. a square) that are stored together in a larger matrix ("bbox_matrix_sp").

```
SpatialPolygons(list(
    Polygons(list(Polygon(bbox_matrix_sp[1:5,])), "reh1"),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(bbox_matrix_sp[6:10,])), "reh2"),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(bbox_matrix_sp[11:15,])), "reh3"),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(bbox_matrix_sp[16:20,])), "reh4"),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(bbox_matrix_sp[21:25,])), "reh5"),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(bbox_matrix_sp[26:30,])), "reh6"),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(bbox_matrix_sp[31:35,])), "reh7"),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(bbox_matrix_sp[36:40,])), "reh8"),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(bbox_matrix_sp[41:45,])), "reh9"),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(bbox_matrix_sp[46:50,])), "reh10"),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(bbox_matrix_sp[51:55,])), "reh11"),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(bbox_matrix_sp[56:60,])), "reh12"),
    Polygons(list(Polygon(bbox_matrix_sp[61:65,])), "reh13")
    )) -> sp_re_alle
```

This seems a little bit tedious, especially if the number of Polygons within the SpatialPolygon increases.

Is there a faster, more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using a `lapply`, e.g.:

```
x = c(0,1,1,0,0)
y = c(0,0,1,1,0)
bbox_matrix_sp = cbind(rep(x,13),rep(y,13))
require(sp)
sp_re_alle = SpatialPolygons(lapply(1:13, function(x) Polygons(list(Polygon(bbox_matrix_sp[((x-1)*5+1):(x*5),])), paste0("reh",x))))
```

in case you are converting grids into polygons, there are direct conversion methods in sp, as in

```
demo(meuse, ask = FALSE) 
m.p = as(meuse.grid, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
```